# How to obtain projections for a matrix along a specific line?

Tags: matlab, projection, tomography-reconstruction

Given parametrization of points on line `L(t,θ)` is
`x(s):= t cos θ − s sin θ`
`y(s):= t sin θ + s cos θ`, where `t` is the distance from the origin to the line at the angle `θ` from `x-axis`, and `s` is some point on the line.

How to take projections of image `Img` at this line `L(t,θ)` with specific step size `s`. Using this I have to implement a radon transform further.

My question is how to define step size `s` and value of `t` ?
Also, do I need to rotate `Img` or without rotation is it possible?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you have a look at the multiple Open source software that are around.

In tomography, rotating the image is the same as rotating the machine around, so you could change the source/detector position per angle and then compute the line that joins them. Then, the step size is up to you. Research has shown (I have tested this) that a good value is `s=pixel_size/2` or `0.5` if you are working in standard pixels.

*If you are doing 2D parallel beam* then you can forget about all the geometric transformations that need to be performed and generate projections by using `imrotate`. If you are using fan beam or cone beam, then the code gets a bit more complicated.

Comment: @M.B. It is OK for a rough approximation, however it limits the geometrical possibilities greatly. You can do a nice demo with it, but forget about real data in general